# Is it possible to add event handler for nameless UI control programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-8

The problem that i have been facing is, I need to programmatically add event handler for an UI control (e.g. textbox) for which Name property is not set in Xaml. Does framework define any Name for such controls? if No, Can we search for all UI elements defined in the WP8 application by giving its Type?

Comment: You know, the first question, I should ask, is _WHY_ do you want to work with no-name control? Yes, you can search a list of elements with needed type and perhaps even determine the one, you want to work with. But wouldn't it be much easier just to set a name for this control?

Comment: Thanks for quick response Olter. I am actually working with Mono Cecil library to inject/alter the handlers of UI controls. Now, since the app does not belong to me and if it contains nameless UI Controls, I would have no way out to change their event handler. that's the reason I thought to populate all the controls of a specific type and add/change the handlers.

Comment: I got it. VisualTreeHelper class did the work.